# how to move a project between groups in Gitlab Ce

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I want to know how to change group of a project in gitlab. i have 3 gitlab projects in a group called "infra" and I created 2 other project without a group. now I want to move them to the Infra group but i cant see any way in gitlab-ce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using the web-UI, navigate to the project
2. From the sidebar, select Settings->General
3. Scroll down and expand "Advanced"
4. Scroll down to the "Transfer Project" box
5. Select a new namespace and click "Transfer project"